I think I over pruned this rubber tree plant and I am scared I killed it, any advice would be appreciated
I had an extremely leggy rubber tree plant that I was gifted and based off the advice I was given I cut all the stems to 6". It has been nearly 2 months and I have not seen any growth. Im not sure if I misunderstood and overpruned or if this is a normal process that just need more time. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!


@kevinskio any help would be really appreciated as you helped on my initial post!

I don't see any reason why the stems won't bud out in four to eight weeks.  The soil does look dry so check how wet it is by sticking your finger in the soil.  If the tip of your finger feels moist then leave it be.

increase light
decrease the amount of watering from your regular schedule until new growth starts
do not repot
do not fertilize
verify that the plant has drainage.  Is there a tray underneath the pot to catch excess water added at the top?


Just to clarify, are you saying you would expect growth in another 4-8 weeks or that it should have already had buds in the 4-8 weeks? I can try to increase the light altough it is sitting under a pretty powerful grow light (Sansi 36 W) and is by the window. I have been letting the soil completely dry out between waterings and have been watering until I see water in the tray and then stopping. Is there anything else I might be missing?

Yes, 4 to 8 weeks till buds on the stems, might be less.  However when you say, completely dry out....are you using a water meter, your finger???  Letting it get totally dry will not help

I have just been using my finger and seeing if the soil is dry at 1-2 inches deep. Is there a better method?

Your finger is a great tool for detecting moisture, carry on!
